# How to use flutter_tex (Flutter) with light mode?

Tags: android, flutter, frontend, latex, lightmode

I'm using the package `flutter_tex 4.0.3` and I have a problem: if I understood correctly, flutter_tex uses a webview, and apparently the flutter webview forces the dark mode when the dark mode of Android is enabled.

More clearly, how do I use flutter_tex with the light mode ? How do I disable the dark mode in Flutter when it's enabled on the Android device that I use ?

Here is my code :

```dart
class _Maths extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Maths({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const TeXView(
      renderingEngine: TeXViewRenderingEngine.katex(),
      child: TeXViewDocument(
        r"""<h3>$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$</h3>""",
        style: TeXViewStyle(
          textAlign: TeXViewTextAlign.Center,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white, // still dark ;(
        ),
      ),
      style: TeXViewStyle(
        margin: TeXViewMargin.all(5),
        padding: TeXViewPadding.all(10),
        border: TeXViewBorder.all(
          TeXViewBorderDecoration(
            borderColor: Colors.blue,
            borderStyle: TeXViewBorderStyle.Solid,
            borderWidth: 1,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white, // still dark ;(
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The "backgroundColor" property set to "Colors.white" doesn't work, whereas it works for any other color...

I tried the following "solutions":

- Besides, this doesn't work either in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```xml
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
```

- The widget "Theme"

```dart
Theme(
   data: ThemeData.light(),
   child: TeXView(...),
),
```

- The `SystemChrome` class from flutter package `services`:

```dart
void main() {
  // ...
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light),
  );
}
```

- `themeMode` & `theme` properties from `MaterialApp`:

```dart
MaterialApp(
   themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
   theme: ThemeData.light(),
   // ...
);
```

I'm completely lost. My goal is to display an equation on a white background, that's all and I wanna scream with pain...

Result: [image: My problem]

Note: flutter_tex is the only package I can use because of the null safety.

Please, help me

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? I tested on my Google Pixel 2 and am not having the same problem. If the equation is showing properly, but the whole screen surrounding it is black, have you tried wrapping your `TeXView()` widget with a `Scaffold()`?

Comment: I added the result. I'm already using a Scaffold that contains, as a child, the TeXView.
The problem is that my android device forces the dark mode. I would love to disable that easily via Flutter.